# How to get the height from the top of character to its base line (i.e, its actual ascent) in QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qfontmetrics

I am experimenting to build a tool that can display modified text (i.e, with some additional stroke) on screen using QWidget. So, to put the stroke in its correct position, I need to know the ascent height of the character the stroke is being put on.

And I'm a tad stuck on retrieving the *actual ascent* of a character. I have tried some of the following things:

- The method `QFontMetrics::ascent()` will give me the ascent of the whole font; so this is not what I need.
- The method `QFontMetrics::boundingRect(&char).height()` will give me what I want as long as the character **does not** use any of its descent part. If the character, however, **does** use *some* of the descent, then the method will return me the actual *height* of the character. If the character *does* use *all* its descent (i.e, the font descent); then I can minus that out to get the actual ascent. But I just don't know how to settle the case, where the character just use a tad of its descent.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`QFontMetrics::boundingRect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect).  The `QRect` returned will have its origin at (0, 0) with the ascent for character `c` represented by...

```
-QFontMetrics::boundingRect(c).top()
```

and, similarly, the descent by...

```
QFontMetrics::boundingRect(c).bottom()
```